# null check operator used on a null value FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink()

Tags: flutter, firebase

```
void fetchLinkData() async {
  final PendingDynamicLinkData? link = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
  print("link" + link.toString());  --> null check operator used on a null value
  handleLinkData(link!);
  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink;
}

void handleLinkData(PendingDynamicLinkData data) {
  final Uri? uri = data?.link;
  if(uri != null) {
    final queryParams = uri.queryParameters;
    if(queryParams.length > 0) {
      String? userName = queryParams["/wellness"];
      // verify the username is parsed correctly
      print("My users username is: $userName");
      Get.toNamed(RouteConstants.wellnessRoute);
    }
  }
}
```

i am having an error of null check operator when i am hitting url link..............................................